# Is ChatGPT Studio Bug Finder Correct When Checking C Code For Error Handling

Tags: c, windows, debugging, openai-api

Given the following code snippet, taken from a larger .c file, ran through ChatGPT Visual Studios 2022 bug finder extension;

```
errno_t err;
wchar_t* wcMessage;

err = wcstombs_s(&i, pFilePath, FILENAME_MAX, pszFilePath, FILENAME_MAX - 1); 
if (err != 0)
{
    // Show the user an error message
    wcMessage = L"LoadFile() wcstombs_s Error: ";        
    ShowErrorMessage(hWnd, wcMessage, err);
    return 0;
}
```

ChatGPT bug finder reports that "*Bug 1: The code does not check the return value of wcstombs_s. If the return value is not 0, the code does not handle the error*".

Question: Is ChatGPT bug finder correct in its findings, if so, how?

What have I tried? Currently I haven't tried anything to change this because I am unsure if this is a false positive reported by ChatGPT.

What was I expecting? I was expecting that ChatGPT did not report this as a bug.

Comment: _"ChatGPT bug finder"_ - whoever named that tool needs be whacked with truth-in-advertising laws...

Comment: By "return value" it may be referring to the `size_t* pReturnValue` parameter, in which case it is correct because your code doesn't currently dereference or use `i`.

Comment: `(wchar_t*)"LoadFile() wcstombs_s Error: "` <-- You shouldn't be casting a non-wide (`char`) string literal to `wchar_t*` - you'll probably end up with gibberish CJK output.

Comment: The ShowErrorMessage() function takes wchar_t*, which is required by _wcserror_s(), which is then formatted with swprintf_s(), then output with MessageBoxW().

Comment: I got the code snippet for wcsrombs_s from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcstombs-s-wcstombs-s-l?view=msvc-170

Comment: ...do you understand _why_ doing `(wchar_t*)"nonwide string literal"` won't work? See here for an example: https://onlinegdb.com/_CW13iSTg

Comment: The code-snippet from MS's example for `wcstombs_s` _does not_ test the return value, but your posted code does - your posted code doesn't match the article at all, in fact...

Comment: Yeah, I understand, I just cast it to suppress a warning while I focused on building the ShowErrorMessage() function. But you've clearly made this at the front of my ToDo list, thank you.

Comment: Please explain how you got your current code with `err = wcstombs_s` when the MS doc page you linked to doesn't match your code at all.

Comment: I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcstombs-s-wcstombs-s-l?view=msvc-170), took the code snippet, and changed it to suit my needs. Adding the errno_t err; and checking the return value based on what I interpreted by what I had read. I.e "_Return value
Zero if successful, an error code on failure_". And, "_the function returns an error code and sets errno_".

Comment: Which errno_t is an int, which is passed to _wcserror_s, which gets a system error message...Is that good enough for you?

Comment: With the assumption that you show us the checked code: Interpreting the bug diagnostic more or less literally, ChatGPT is wrong, as so often. We still need to learn to distrust AI. ChatGPT has **no understanding** of the code, it just associates certain patterns to "learned" outputs. It does this extremely fast on a huge data background, and this leads to the impression that it is smart. It is not.

Comment: @Dai To be fair, ChatGPT demonstrating that ChatGPT itself is buggy/broken/fundamentally FUBAR **is** is a form of "bug finder"... ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee _Emergent behaviour_ in LLMs is downright spooky though - one of the first things I ever tried with ChatGPT back in December 2022 was to ask it to write a C# program to solve Factorio transport belt routing problems - while it wasn't perfect, and had a few small hallucinations, it flabbergasted me because _there is no way_ OpenAI somehow trained it on that very, very, very specific task - and when it was done I asked it to translate it to Haskell (as a joke...) and my jaw hit the floor.